# Performance of singleton JDBC connection vs multiple connections

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm wondering why using a singleton JDBC connection is faster than using multiple JDBC connections. The obvious answer is that using a single connection is faster than multiple, as the process of creating a connection is rather resource-intensive.

I'm looking for a in depth explanation into why that is.

I tested the following singleton method and multiple method.

#### Singleton

```
@Component
public class ConnectionService {
  
    private static Connection connection = null;

    static {
        String url = "REDACTED";
        String user = "REDACTED";
        String pass = "REDACTED";
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection()
    {
        return connection;
    }
```

#### Multiple

```
public Connection establishConnection() {
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("REDACTED", "REDACTED", "REDACTED");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("No connection");
    }
    return connection;
}
```

#### Test

I tested the performance of both methods, these are the results.

[image]

Comment: "*The obvious answer is that using a single connection is faster than multiple, as the process of creating a connection is rather ressource instense*". You answered your own question. I/O is slow

Comment: You've just invented a poor man's datasource, with brittle resource management (consider what happens if code using that singleton solution closes the connection, like normal JDBC code should do when it is finished). Now test it using a connection pool like HikariCP, which allows you to reuse connections (and takes care of replacing broken connections).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using multiple threads, each thread should have its own connection.  Otherwise, a singleton is the 'right' way to go.